# will_paginate 3.0 is not compatible with Rails 2.3 or older (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, will-paginate

When I run `rails -v` the output is `Rails 3.0.15`. I also have done `gem install rails 2.3.5` which is what the environment.rb files says it needs.

Why am I getting this error when my rails aren't *older* than 2.3.

Comment: And what is your question? Do you want to run Rails 2.x or 3.x? Use will_paginate for Rails 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I just uninstalled the rails 3.0.5 gem. And now I have rails 2.3.5 and 2.3.11. But still I can't get the server up and running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mix Rails 2 and Rails 3, even if both gems are installed. There are two options:

- [Install the 2.3.x version](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Installation) of `will_paginate`
- [Upgrade your app](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#upgrading-to-rails-3) to Rails 3

Comment: Actually, I had just done rake gems:install, and didn't notice that the will_paginate gem was installed for Rails 3.0. Thanks for the help!